# I have a question on the part of jQuery ID Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, selector

```
$(“#id”).val() : No find
$(“input[id=‘id’]”).val() : OK
```

Do you know the difference between the above two situations? Why would you do that?

Comment: Not exactly clear what you are asking

Comment: What about `$("input#id").val()`? Possibility of having multiple elements with _id_ of `id`.

Comment: We need to see your html.

Comment: Guess that you have another element having id="id" but it's not an input.

Comment: You [should not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme) use same `id` for multiple elements (not even when they are different types), if you think it is needed you can probably use `class` instead.

Comment: @josephting I used only one id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking why:

```js
$(“#id”).val() // <--- This doesn't work,

// and

$(“input[id=‘id’]”).val()  // <--- ... and this does work?
```

Assuming your markup looks something like this:

```
<label for="id"> Input </label> <br />
<input id="id" type="text" value="test"/>
```

... If this is the case, then the following should work (I've included vanilla JS Comparisons for reference, which is pretty close to how jQuery works under the hood anyway).

```js
// The jQuery Way
const firstCase = $("#id").val() // "test"
const secondCase = $("input[id='id']").val() // "test"

// The Vanilla Way
const thirdCase = document.getElementById("id").value; // "test"
const fourthCase = document.querySelector("input[id='id']").value; // "test"
```

Please provide the HTML Markup you are trying to interact with, then we will get a better understanding of the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: `<input type=‘hidden’ id=‘modlId’ />`

Answer (score 2):

To answer this question, we need to understand how Jquery selectors work.

`$("#id")`            Internally uses  `document.getElementById();`

`$("input[id='id']")` Internally uses `document.getElementsByTagName()` to get all the matching 'Element tag' and filters with id.

The main difference between both operations is case 1 returns only the matching object, but case 2 returns along with prevObj or the containing object.

Hence technically both operation with `val()` should return the same result.

Comment: But in reality, the first selector is not found and the second selector only gets the value.